# OVER clause for VARCHAR

Tags: sql, netezza

I can use over clause for numeric and date columns using an aggregate function. But, I'm stuck with being unable to use over clause for the varchar column. In the example below, I can reproduce the FIRST_FILL_DT column using the following lines:

```
MIN(FILL_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS FIRST_FILL_DT
```

However, when trying to produce the FIRST_BP_MED column, I am not sure if I can use similar syntax because I don't know if the aggregate function works correctly with VARCHAR Columns.

Can anyone please offer insights or guidance on how to solve this?

My data is like this:

[image]

My desired data should like this:

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [mre]: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. (3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above. (4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question, no images.

Comment: What's the PK of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database supports the FIRST_VALUE window function, you can use something like this:

```
FIRST_VALUE(BP_MED) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FILL_DATE) AS first_bp_med
```

Docs for FIRST_VALUE:

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15),
[Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html),
[SQLite](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward. Use 'FIRST_VALUE'  over your window clause to pick the first value omitted by your partition irrespective of the condition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT 
    ID, FILL_DATE, BP_MED, 
    MIN (FILL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FILL_DATE) AS FIRST_FILL_DT, 
    FIRST_VALUE (BP_MED) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FILL_DATE) AS FIRST_BP_MED
FROM 
    YOURTABLE;
```